# Is it safe to derive a secret from a signature?

Tags: public-key, signature, key-derivation, terminology

Many blockchain users have wallets that hold a private key, which can interact with a website. For example, the website can request the wallet to sign a specific message.

'Do only sign this message if you trust the frontend and you want to give it access to your private key used for XYZ.'

From the deterministic signature, a deterministic key can be derived that can be use in the application 'XYZ'. This technique has the advantage that as long as the user has access to their wallet, they should be able also derive the key for application 'XYZ' without the need to store a new key.

Does this technique have a name? Is it safe?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://www.ledger.com/academy/crypto/what-are-hierarchical-deterministic-hd-wallets)? Note that the keys are still generated from a secret and not from a signature. Signatures are meant to be public and should not be used to derive secrets.

Comment: No, I indeed mean schemes where the signature is used as a seed for another key. I understand that is not the way signatures are intended to be used but that alone seems to me not a sufficient reason not to do it.

Comment: Here is a blog post that covers the idea more: https://medium.com/loopring-protocol/looprings-new-approach-to-generating-layer-2-account-keys-4a16cc334906